# Qual o critério para se ter outros níveis de acesso no chat, além de público?

Tags: suporte, chat

Vi que nos chats há um nível de acesso, porém até o momento somente visualizo a opção pública.

O que é preciso para um chat passar ter opções mais privadas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Com 100 pontos de reputação, você pode criar uma sala pública
- Com 1.000 pontos, você pode criar uma sala tipo "galeria" (onde você escolhe quem pode falar, mas qualquer um pode ler).
- Para criar uma sala privada, você precisa ser moderador ♦

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges